# Add file specific good words to internal vim wordlist (via modeline)

Tags: vim, spell-check

Is it possible to add correctly spelled words to vim's internal wordlist via modeline? Or another file specific method?

Vim can add words to the temporary internal-wordlist via key command `zG` or `:spellgood! {word}`. Can the same be done on the modeline?

An example would be following text where I want the acronyms "RAS" and "RAP" to be considered good words when using vim's spell checking.

> RAS syndrome (short for "redundant acronym syndrome syndrome"), also
>   known as PNS syndrome ("PIN number syndrome syndrome", which expands
>   to "personal identification number number syndrome syndrome") or RAP
>   phrases ("redundant acronym phrase phrases"), refers to the use of one
>   or more of the words that make up an acronym or initialism in
>   conjunction with the abbreviated form, thus in effect repeating one or
>   more words.

Text was copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently Vim provides no "native" mechanism to do this, although I think it is a good idea.  The only thing I can think of is an `:autocmd` that calls a function that searches for a special section in the file and then moves the cursor over the words in that section and triggers `zG` with `:normal` commands.  This would be messy and I would be reluctant to bother with it.

***Edit:*** Of course, somehow I overlooked the existence of `:spellgood!`, even though it is in your question.  This makes the job much more feasible.  I came up with a basic implementation which you can tweak to fit your needs:

```
function! AutoSpellGoodWords()
    let l:goodwords_start = search('\C-\*-SpellGoodWordsStart-\*-', 'wcn')
    let l:goodwords_end = search('\C-\*-SpellGoodWordsEnd-\*-', 'wcn')
    if l:goodwords_start == 0 || l:goodwords_end == 0
        return
    endif
    let l:lines = getline(l:goodwords_start + 1, l:goodwords_end - 1)
    let l:words = []
    call map(l:lines, "extend(l:words, split(v:val, '\\W\\+'))")
    for l:word in l:words
        silent execute ':spellgood! ' . l:word
    endfor
endfunction

autocmd BufReadPost * call AutoSpellGoodWords()
```

This will search for a block that looks something like this:

```
-*-SpellGoodWordsStart-*-
word1 word2 word3
word4 word5 ...
-*-SpellGoodWordsEnd-*-
```

And each word it finds--in this case, `word1`, `word2`, `word3`, `word4`, and `word5`--within the block it will add to the temporary good words list.

Just be aware that I have not stress-tested this.

Comment: This is more in depth than I expected, and it would make a very useful vim script. I did check vim.org, but there weren't any similar matches. Thanks!